# AS3.0 play sound without delay

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I've got a couple of classes.

My document class (Main.as) instantiates the class player and Soundsloader. 
In the player class when the player picks up an item in the game, i want to play a short sound. I do this with the following code: `MovieClip(this.main_object.sound_loader).playPickUp();`

In my document class i also instantiate the SoundsLoader which basically should load all the sounds. 
(just one in my sample code below)

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class SoundsLoader extends MovieClip{

        private var pick_up_item:sound_pickup_item =  new sound_pickup_item;

        public function SoundsLoader() {
        }

        public function playPickUp(){
            pick_up_item.play();
        }
    }
}
```

However when i use the methods my swf file freezes for a moment, plays the sound and then continues. So what's the best way of doing this ? (i'm using a .wav sound)

Comment: There is a delay while using a mp3, before and after a sound.
I always wanted solve this problem.
Even with the as3wavsound class, there is a delay at the first play of the sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this only happens the first time that you play the sound, maybe due to decompressing issues. I discard download latency because you told that you are already loading all the sounds, in a preloader or something like that.

Like I said, if this **only happens the first time**, a workaround would be to play all the sounds at the preload time, but muted.

Example:

```
public function SoundsLoader() {            
    var songController:SoundChannel = pick_up_item.play();          
    var volControl:SoundTransform = songController.soundTransform;
    volControl.volume = 0;
    songController.soundTransform = volControl;
}
```

Or

```
public function SoundsLoader() {            
    var songController:SoundChannel = pick_up_item.play();          
    songController.stop;
}
```

Comment: Playing 'em muted, is kind of an ugly solution. I hope someone knows a better solution. Otherwise i'll flag yours as the best answer.

Comment: Yes, it's an ugly hack. But try if it works, so you can narrow the problem.

Comment: Yeah it works i edited your post in case anyone is looking for the right answer.